# PHP MySQL loop through the rows and print date when the date changes

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, group-by

My `messages` table is like this:

```
id : (auto increment)
incoming_msg_id : (receiver's user id, BIGINT)
outgoing_msg_id : (sender's user id, BIGINT)
msg : (message content, LONGTEXT)
created_at : (timestamp)
```

This is my query used for fetching messages:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM messages
                       LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = messages.outgoing_msg_id
                       WHERE (outgoing_msg_id = :omsg AND incoming_msg_id = :imsg) OR (outgoing_msg_id = :imsg AND incoming_msg_id = :omsg)
                       ORDER BY messages.id ASC");
$stmt-> bindValue(':imsg', $imsg);
$stmt-> bindValue(':omsg', sessionUser());
$stmt-> execute();
```

I want to use `created_at` timestamp field to group messages in such a way so that I can display `date` when the message transactions took place.

For example:

```
5th July, 2021

Message 1
Message 2

6th July, 2021

Message 3
Message 4
```

I therefore want to print a new header containing date each time the date changes. My current PHP loop goes like this:

```
while($f = $stmt->fetch()){

  // HERE, I WANT TO CHECK IF DATE CHANGES AND PRINT A NEW HEADER, FOR EXAMPLE
  // if(dateChanges){ echo date('jS M, Y', strtotime($f['created_at'])); } // UNSURE, OF LOGIC INSIDE IF STATEMENT

  if($f['outgoing_msg_id'] == sessionUser()){
    $html .= "<div class='chat outgoing'>
                <div class='details d-flex'>
                  <div class='textmsgbox'>
                    <div class='thechatmsg'>".decrypt($f['msg'], ENCRYPTION_KEY)."</div>
                    <div class='tmbcontent d-flex'>
                      <small>".date('h:i a', strtotime($f['created_at']))."</small>
                      <small class='seen'>$seen</small>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>";
  }else{
    $html .= "<div class='chat incoming'>
                <div class='details d-flex'>
                  <div class='textmsgbox'>
                    <div class='thechatmsg'>".decrypt($f['msg'], ENCRYPTION_KEY)."</div>
                    <div class='tmbcontent'>
                      <small>".date('h:i a', strtotime($f['created_at']))."</small>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>";
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to store the date of the current row in a variable.  Then, next time you loop you can compare the variable to the new current date, and see if it's changed or not

Comment: @ADyson I think the answer by Shreyansh Kashyap does exactly what you suggested. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple. First you need to declare a `null` variable outside of the loop and then check the timestamp's date against it and print the date. Then at the end you can update the previously defined `null` variable with the date from the timestamp and you are done. Have a look at the code below:

```
$lastDate = null; // DECLARE A NULL VARABLE FOR THE LAST DATE
while($f = $stmt->fetch()){
  $chatDate = null; // DECLARE A NULL VARIABLE HERE TO AVOID MULTIPLE OUTPUTS
  
  // CHECK AGAINST THE LAST DATE IF IT EQUALS TO THE TIMESTAMP'S DATE, IF NOT, PRINT THE DATE
  if($lastDate !== date('Y-m-d', strtotime($f['created_at']))) {

    // I ADDED THIS ADDITIONAL CODE SO THAT YOU CAN PRINT THE DATE AS "TODAY" & "YESTERDAY" 
    // You may remove this if you don't want

    if(date('Y-m-d', strtotime($f['created_at'])) == date('Y-m-d')){
      $cd = "TODAY";
    }else if(date('Y-m-d', strtotime($f['created_at'])) == date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 day'))){
      $cd = "YESTERDAY";
    }else{
      $cd = date('jS F, Y', strtotime($f['created_at']));
    }

    $chatDate = "<div class='chat-date'>".$cd."</div>";
  }

  $html .= $chatDate;

  // YOUR IF....ELSE CONDITION GOES HERE
  if(){
    // Your code as in question
  }else{
    // Your code as in question
  }

  // UPDATE THE NULL VARIABLE WITH CURRENT DATE
  $lastDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($f['created_at'])); 
}
```

Done! As simple as that. Enjoy :)

Comment: Works like a charm... Also, Plus 1 for `TODAY` and `YESTERDAY` checks :) Thanks!